# PIC on 3 volts power

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I made a personal count down timer with PIC16F628A and two multiplexed  seven segment LEDs. The system was tested on breadboard at 5 volts USB . However, I intend to work them on batteries at low power consumption. Is it advisable to power the whole system by 3 volts by AA batteries ?

Answer (score 3):

No. The PIC16F628A only works down to 3V, according to the datasheet. The LF version works down to 2V. Even with brand new AA batteries, the voltage will quickly drop below 3V, and can cause issues.

Solutions. Use 3x AA for 4.5V nominal, or use a boost converter to bring up 1x AA or 2xAA to a stable 3~5V.

Answer (score 1):

The PIC can operate with the lower voltage. The only thing I am unsure of is if your seven segment LEDs will have enough forward bias voltage to operate at the lower voltage. For some segment displays 3V isn't enough. My suggestion is (if you can't find the required forward bias voltage) try it and if it doesn't work add another AA battery in series to get 4.5V.

Comment: Yea..I will try both solutions...

Comment: A typical 3.2V ~ 3.6V single led segment display will work at 3V, just at a lower brightness and current compared to it's max recommended 20mA. 10mA and 2.x volts is common and frankly almost as bright as the 20mA drive. Logarithmic visual response.

Answer (score 1):

As said, it's not a good idea to do it. In fact, all your component will work at 3V but this voltage level isn't guaranteed overtime due to battery discharge. What you should do is to increase a bit the input voltage and then use a regulator to have a fix voltage output. This solution will consume a bit more power (due to regulator power loss) but it is safer for the whole circuit.

By the way, if the input voltage change, you may also need to change some resistor value for LED driving. It's not that important since the voltage difference is pretty low but still !